# How to delete lists of rows?

Tags: mysql, excel, delete-row

I have an excel file with about 1500 rows of business' and I need to delete those business' from my MySQL database. How can I do this? I'm using the business ID as the cell which identifies the rows.

So in file A I have 1,500 rows of business IDs
In file B I have +50,000 rows of business'

And I need to delete business' that are in file A from file B.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: The answer below seems to be correct. Did you face any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Import the excel file into a temporary table (here called TEMP), then

```
delete from businesses where id in (select distinct id from TEMP)
```

Comment: It makes the query but doesn't remove any rows. There might be something wrong with my query?

delete from PLD_LINK where STATE in (select distinct "COL 1" from TEMP)

STATE is the column where the business id is located in file B
COL 1 is the column where the business id is located in file A

I created a table called TEMP where I imported the rows...

Comment: "COL 1" is not a valid column identifier in MySQL, \`COL 1\` is. Backticks instead of quote marks.